# Use `data.table` to get first of subgroup based on a variable

Tags: r, data.table

Consider a data set consisting of a grouping variable (here `id`) and an ordered variable (here `date`)

```
(df <- data.frame(
  id = rep(1:2,2),
  date = 4:1
))
#   id date
# 1  1    4
# 2  2    3
# 3  1    2
# 4  2    1
```

I'm wondering what the easiest way is in `data.table` to do the equivalent of this `dplyr` code:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(min_rank(date)==1)
# Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
# Groups: id
# 
#   id date
# 1  1    2
# 2  2    1
```

i.e. for each `id` get the first according to `date`.

Based on a similar stackoverflow question ([Create an "index" for each element of a group with data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658424/create-an-index-for-each-element-of-a-group-with-data-table)), I came up with this

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
setkey(dt, id, date)
for(k in unique(dt$id)){
  dt[id==k, index := 1:.N]
}
dt[index==1,]
```

But it seems like there should be a one-liner for this. Being unfamiliar with `data.table` I thought something like this

```
dt[,,mult="first", by=id]
```

should work, but alas! The last bit of code seems like it should group by `id` and then take the first (which within `id` would be determined by `date` since I've set the keys in this way.)

---

EDIT

Thanks to Ananda Mahto, this one-liner will now be in my `data.table` repertoire

```
dt[,.SD[1], by=id]
#    id date
# 1:  1    2
# 2:  2    1
```

Comment: Would something like this work for you: `setkey(as.data.table(df), id, date)[, .SD[1], by = id]`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg, the milliseconds are killing me slowly :-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto, Ok, added a benchmark on a huge data set, and you are right, everything performs more or less the same, except that binary search is a bit better

Comment: @DavidArenburg, are you sure it's not just `sequence` that is slowing things down :-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto, it maybe, cause for different `seed`s I'm getting different results too. Either way, it is a good thing to introduce binary search to `data.table` users

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Working directly with your source `data.frame`, you can try:

```
setkey(as.data.table(df), id, date)[, .SD[1], by = id]
#    id date
# 1:  1    2
# 2:  2    1
```

---

Extending your original idea, you can just do:

```
dt <- data.table(df)
setkey(dt, id, date)
dt[, index := sequence(.N), by = id][index == 1]
#    id date index
# 1:  1    2     1
# 2:  2    1     1
```

---

It might be that at a certain scale, David is correct about `head` vs `[1]`, but I'm not sure what scale that would be.

```
set.seed(1)
nrow <- 10000
ncol <- 20

df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(10, nrow * ncol, TRUE), nrow = nrow, ncol = ncol))

fun1 <- function() setkey(as.data.table(df), X1, X2)[, head(.SD, 1), by = X1]
fun2 <- function() setkey(as.data.table(df), X1, X2)[, .SD[1], by = X1]

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(fun1(), fun2())
# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
#  fun1() 12.178189 12.496777 13.400905 12.808523 13.483545 30.28425   100
#  fun2()  4.474345  4.554527  4.948255  4.620596  4.965912  8.17852   100
```

Comment: Why do you use `.SD` instead of `date`? Why don't you use `setDT`?

Comment: @Roland, is it mandatory that I do those things? What if there are more columns other than "date"? What if I don't want to convert my input to a `data.table`?

Comment: No, of course not. The question is specific for one column. Why wouldn't you?

Comment: `sequence` is an `unlist` and `lapply` wrapper, why not just `seq_len(.N)`?

Comment: @Roland, because I strongly feel that SO shouldn't be about just answering a single person's question. I don't always want to be using `setDT` and then `setkey` if I don't have an easy way to go back to the earlier sorting of my `data.frame` (in case that were important).

Comment: @DavidArenburg, there is an "edit" link and you are more than welcome to use it.

Comment: I don't do that without OPs agreement (unless there is a mistake in the answer)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option using `data.table`s binary search

```
setkey(dt[, indx := seq_len(.N), by = id], indx)[J(1)]
#    id date indx
# 1:  1    2    1
# 2:  2    1    1
```

---

Some benchmarks:
It seems that all the methods perform more or less the same, but on huge data set (`1e+06*1e+2`) binrary search wins

```
set.seed(1)
nrow <- 1e6
ncol <- 1e2

df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(10, nrow * ncol, TRUE), nrow = nrow, ncol = ncol))
library(data.table)

funAM1 <- function() setkey(as.data.table(df), X1, X2)[, .SD[1], by = X1]
funAM2 <- function() setkey(as.data.table(df), X1, X2)[, index := sequence(.N), by = X1][index == 1]
funDA1 <- function() setkey(as.data.table(df), X1, X2)[, head(.SD, 1), by = X1]
funDA2 <- function() setkey(as.data.table(df)[, indx := seq_len(.N), by = X1], X1)[J(1)]

library(microbenchmark)
Res <- microbenchmark(funAM1(), funAM2(), funDA1(), funDA2())
Res
# Unit: milliseconds
#     expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
# funAM1() 737.5690 758.3015 771.9344 794.1417 910.1019   100
# funAM2() 631.7822 693.8286 704.6912 729.6960 806.5556   100
# funDA1() 757.0327 772.4353 784.3107 810.0759 938.6344   100
# funDA2() 564.7291 578.1089 587.6470 611.7269 740.4077   100
boxplot(Res)
```

[image]